# В какой директории windows должен находиться libintl.h?

Tags: windows, golang, gui

Использую библиотеку gotk3, выполнил инструкции по установке: https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/wiki/Installing-on-Windows

`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` выдает корректный результат.

Пытаюсь собрать тестовый проект и получаю ошибку:

```
# github.com/gotk3/gotk3/glib
In file included from ./glib.go.h:31:0,
                 from D:\GOPATH\src\github.com\gotk3\gotk3\glib\application.go:7:
C:/Fedora/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n.h:25:21: fatal error: libintl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libintl.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

При попытке использовать `go get github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk` получаю аналогичную ошибку... 
Сам необходимый файл лежит в `C:\Fedora\include`

Где этот файл должен лежать что-бы код заработал?

Comment: Может вам лучше сменить библиотеку на [go-walk](https://github.com/lxn/walk) , [gxui](https://github.com/google/gxui) или [ui](https://github.com/andlabs/ui) ?

Comment: @GreenDragon можно бы, но они достаточно давно не обновлялись, одна год, а вторая с августа... искал что имеет сообщество и развивается...

Comment: Может требования конкретно вашей задачи уже реализованы? Смотрите не что чаще обновляется, а что есть для решения проблемы.

Comment: Символы <> говорят о том что ваш libintl.h должен быть среди системных папок компилятора (обычно это папка include)

Comment: @nick_n_a так файл и лежит в `C:\Fedora\include` и эта папка добавлена в Path

Comment: Компилятор такие файлы берёт из **своей** папки include, а не из path. Читайте+настраивайте опции компилятора (там есть раздел Include files directory).